# Exclude specific urls from resolving in dnscrypt-proxy

Tags: dns, filtering

I have dnscrypt-proxy set up on my Linux work machine, and am able to use it to browse the internet.  However, I have several internal company sites I need to access and require an internal dns server to resolve their urls.

I would like to be able to use my company's internal dns server for all internal company sites, while still be able to use dnscrypt-proxy for external websites (such as stackoverflow.com).

Can anyone tell me how to do this on Linux?

Answer (score 0):

The recommended way to use dnscrypt-proxy is [behind a DNS cache](https://dnscrypt.org/#dns-cache) such as dnsmasq or unbound.

Both have the ability to direct queries for certain domains to specific resolvers.